# Lua module invocation with require returns boolean

Tags: module, lua, require

i have wrote the next lua module:

```
    --mod.lua
    local M = {}        
    function M.bar()
    print "bar"
    end
    return M
```

And i'm trying to use it on another lua script as:

```
    --main.lua
    function Main(context)
    local mod = require 'mod'
    mod.bar()
    end
```

But i am getting the error : "attempt to index ? (a boolean value)" on the line "mod.bar()"
The same result is obtained if i use module(..., package.seeall) on the header of mod.lua. 
Could anybody help me?

Comment: It seems that your module has returned `nil` instead of a table.  A typo in the module?

Comment: Are you sure that you pasted the functions correctly? The program works fine on my end.

Comment: The only thing that comes till my mind is that require doesn't load appropriate file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to W.B. my 'mod.lua' was in another path. Sorry for wasting your time.